# How to import xml file in spring boot app without using "ImportResource" annotation

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@ImportResource({"classpath:dubbo.xml"})
//I want to specify the xml file with command line arguments at run time
public class App  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // How to import the XML file now?
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

I want to specify the XML file with command line arguments at run time then import it in main method. What can I do?

Comment: Instead of providing a method stub, please provide what you have tried, this will help us to get to the bottom of your issue, we are a help channel, not a tutorial, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class, "classpath:dubbo.xml");
app.run(args);
```

The SpringApplication [constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#SpringApplication-java.lang.Object...-) accepts Objects.
A valid source is one of: a class, class name, package, package name, or an XML resource location (see e.g. [SpringApplication.setSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#setSources-java.util.Set-)s).

If you would like to make the configuration file configurable by command line arguments you need to parse the arguments and adjust parameter values of course.